# swipe for tableviewcells in swift2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

How we can do the left swipe and right swipe in swift2

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     //   print("Commit Editing Style \(editingStyle)")
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did you add this method:    // Individual rows can opt out of having the -editing property set for them. If not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable.
    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool

Comment: @FrancescStudio i want to do swipe actions from both sides in tableview cell. ie swiping from left to right and from right to left

Comment: @AntonyJacob If my answer helpful with you, please mark it as an correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Only available function to help you swipe from right to left**.

Here is the example for it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More") { action, index in
        println("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favorite") { action, index in
        println("favorite button tapped")
    }
    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        println("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [share, favorite, more]
}
```

Then it will look like:

[image]

If you want to swipe from left to right, you need to code yourself, or you can use this library here:

https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

It takes just one method to enable swipe to delete in table views: `tableView(_:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:)`. This method gets called when a user tries to delete one of your table rows using swipe to delete, but its very presence is what enables swipe to delete in the first place – that is, iOS literally checks to see whether the method exists, and, if it does, enables swipe to delete.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        objects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```